# Why projective flat with connected and reduced fibers are Stein morphisms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to S$ be a projective flat morphism with connected and reduced geometric fibers. Why do one have that $O_S\to f_* O_X$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: There are a few potentially helpful comments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26269


Comment: See the answers to part (3) of this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16845/family-of-enriques-surfaces-and-grothendieck-riemann-roch/